# How to limit the tappable area in HStack to make just the delete button tappable

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, tap, hstack

In my ListView, There is a HStack consisting of checkbox, Text, Spacer and a Delete Button. Unfortunately, clicking at any part of the HStack (Checkbox/Text/Spacer area) causing the delete button action firing. How to limit this delete action only applicable for delete button, not the whole HStack view in SwiftUI ListView?

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder public func hidden(_ shouldHide: Bool) -> some View {
        switch shouldHide {
        case true: self.hidden()
        case false: self
        }
    }
}

struct AgendaItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var isSelected = false
}

struct AgendaList: View {
    @State private var agendaItems = [AgendaItem]()
    @State private var newAgendaItem = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Agenda List")
                .font(.title)
            
            HStack {
                ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                    TextEditor(text: $newAgendaItem)
                        .frame(height: 40)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                                .stroke(Color(UIColor.opaqueSeparator), lineWidth: 0.5)
                        )
                    Text("Add agenda")
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                        .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.25))
                        .padding(8)
                        .hidden(!newAgendaItem.isEmpty)
                }
                
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Text("Add")
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .padding()
            
            List(agendaItems) { agendaItem in
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 8) {
                    VStack {
                        CheckBox(isChecked: $agendaItems[getIndex(for: agendaItem.id)].isSelected)
                            .padding(.top, 3)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Text(agendaItem.title)
                        .strikethrough(agendaItem.isSelected)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        deleteItem(at: getIndex(for: agendaItem.id))
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                    }
                }
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.red)
        }
    }
    
    func addItem() {
        agendaItems.append(AgendaItem(title: newAgendaItem))
        newAgendaItem = ""
    }
    
    func getIndex(for id: UUID) -> Int {
        return agendaItems.firstIndex { $0.id == id } ?? 0
    }
    
    func deleteItem(at index: Int) {
        agendaItems.remove(at: index)
    }
}

struct CheckBox: View {
    @Binding var isChecked: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            isChecked.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "square")
                .foregroundColor(isChecked ? .blue : .gray)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere I got, if you add a Button or other tappable view as a child of the HStack, the tappable area will extend to the entire bounds of the HStack.

This behavior is due to the way SwiftUI handles hit testing for user interactions. When a user taps on the screen, SwiftUI determines which view was tapped by recursively testing the hit against each subview in the view hierarchy until it finds a view that contains the hit point. Now how to restrict this hit testing area only to delete button inside the HStack view?

Comment: Is there any way to detect subview type inside of the HStack? I mean detecting only delete button tap action event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding below two properties for button:

```
Button(action: {
    deleteItem(at: getIndex(for: agendaItem.id))
}) {
    Image(systemName: "trash")
}
.onTapGesture { }
.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```

The buttonStyle property of the Button view is set to BorderlessButtonStyle to remove the button's background. The onTapGesture modifier is added to the Button view to handle the tap event, and an empty closure is provided to the onTapGesture modifier to prevent the list row from being tappable.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the wanted behavior by adding the `.buttonStyle(...)` to the `Button` inside the `HStack`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]

    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            HStack {
                Text(item)
                Spacer()
                Button("click me") {
                    print("\(item) button tapped")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderless)
            }
        }
    }
}
```